# Facing issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript. I create a file in same folder and linked it with html. The problem is when I write `alert("Hello World")` so it shows message in browser but when I am trying

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHtml = "Hello world"
```

it does not change the content of my HTML element.

Comment: you probably have an error on the console waiting only you to read it

Comment: [Pictures of code are unhelpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and you really need to open the developer tools in your browser and read the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the JavaScript code is executed **before** your browser loaded the [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp), so it won't work.

Move the `<script src="main.js"></script>` just above `</body>` in your HTML file. This way the DOM gets loaded **before** the JavaScript code.

Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <H1 id="p1">hi</H1>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTML DOM property is [`innerHTML`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp), not `innerHtml`:

```js
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Hello world";
```

```html
<div id="p1"></div>
```

Comment: he is also integrating the script on the head, when it's executed, there is still no DOM to work on